# Small database system as ACL for ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I have a web based ASP.net platform which serves many thousands of clients per day. Roughly 100 connections per minute. This could increase by 10x potentially.

When the clients connect to the system I can identify them uniquely, and I need a simple database which can be queried for 2 things:
1) Is this ID valid?
2) How many IDs are in the database total?

If the ID is not valid, I would ordinarily add it to the database upon first seeing the ID.

I have tried Microsoft SQL CE - but I am now seeing issues with too many sessions. I would like to avoid a dedicated SQL system (SQL Server Express etc) and stick to a more "embedded" option.

What systems would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at SQLite, its a "file based" SQL server and performance could even be better for you when there is no major advanced queries.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: I looked at SQLite and I saw a couple of downsides:
1) .NET bindings are for 2.0 - I am using 4.0 (not major)
2) Read alot about SQLite only using file locks, and I will be reading/writing simultaneously = deadlocking :(

Comment: With the product I work with (Firewall/Gateway) we use SQLite for logging and solved the problem by not write at every request, instead we writing down to the DB/disk at a specific time intervals.

Comment: OK. Is the data available instantly through a query (from memory) or do you see a delay in the results?

Comment: When reading, if the data are not on the cue to be written to disk I would read the DB. If for example writing any queued data to disk every 500ms, you could always reread with a delay. Question is how often will it happen that data just committed need to be read instantly?

Comment: But to be honest.. I would really test the performance with jMeter for example to see if you do get performance problems. SQLite can handle over 20,000 inserts per second of smaller INSERT INTO for example

Comment: I think based on my question this is a good answer - however I solved my issue in a different way. Thanks StefanE